# How to find value in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

I have a few attributes in array. For example size for clothes. I want to check if I have attributes or not. If not I want to display error in file. And the problem is. Why I have error even I compare the same string?

Please, check my code below.

```
foreach ($attributeToCheck as $singleAttributeToCheck) 
            {
                if(!array_search(strtolower($singleAttributeToCheck), array_map('strtolower', array_column($attributes, 'name')))){            
                    $this->errorLog('*  ERROR   *   There is no:' . $singleAttributeToCheck);
                    return FALSE;
                }                
            }

In $attributeToCheck I have those value:
0: "Black"
1: "S"

In strtolower($singleAttributeToCheck) I have value:
"s"

array_map('strtolower', array_column($attributes, 'name')) looks like this:
0: "s"
1: "m"
2: "l"
```

Why I go to errorlog? I have string "s" in my array. Thanks for help.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_search()` function finds the value and return its key and that is not what is needed here, instead you must use `in_array()` function which will return the value to the function

```
<?php
function a($v){
    return(strtolower($v));
}
$attributeToCheck  = array("Black","S");
$attributes =   array('s','m','l');
$array = array_map('a',$attributeToCheck);
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if(!in_array($value,$attributes)){
        echo "Not Found<br>";
    }
    else{
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>
```

[image]

In the mentioned above output the **Not Found** is the result of checking *Black* in the array and **Success** is for checking *S*.